# Block users for cancelling restart PC command line operation

Tags: windows, windows-10, command-line

I am pushing restart to clients PCs using command line as following:

```
shutdown -r -f -t 300
```

The problem is that a simple non-administrator user can enter command line and input

```
shutdown -a
```

This command will cancel the shut down operation.
Is there a way to block the user to cancel the shutdown operation without blocking command line?

Comment: Are you not interested in whether users would lose work?

Comment: Of course yes, this is only part of the script. They are also alerted before in different additional ways.

Comment: Set restarts and updates to happen overnight. Much easier.

Comment: @John, computers are powered off, there is no electricity in the site during the night.

Comment: Fair enough. So set hours of operation to allow for early morning restart or end of day restart. Manage restarts to make life easy, not to anytime and lose work.

Answer (score 0):

`shutdown` is considered an external command to command prompt meaning it relies on the permissions set on the executable which can be found in `C:\Windows\System32\shutdown.exe`

This means you can configure user permissions for it either directly on the file or by creating an AppLocker policy for it if you use GPOs. Be very careful though as changing permissions on system utilities could have unforeseen effects.